# How to test jQuery Ajax with php?

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to just send some information to a php file using Jquery Ajax. I wanted to send some info to the php file every time a click is made.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkbox').click(function() {
        $.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : "test.php",
            data : "ffs=somedata&ffs2=somedata2",
            succes : function() {
                alert("something");
            } 
        });
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox" id = "checkbox">
</body>
```

The php file looks like this:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['ffs'];

?>
```

Now, I see the POST going, (using firebug). I get no errors, but nothing happens in the php file. Also success is never reached, so no alert is triggered. What should I do in the php file so that I can trigger success and also see the sent info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo, change

```
succes : function() {
```

to

```
success : function() {
```

And to retrieve the response from the PHP use

```
success : function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

For [more info see this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)